# Php checking whether a variable is a number or a numeric string

Tags: php

I have two `POST` variables which can either be a `mere String` or a `numerical string`, in either conditions my program is to perform different tasks but the biggest issue is `php` can not seem to give me the right result, well at least that is what I think, I have 4 conditions and two variables; `$_POST['category']` and `$_POST['location']`, one in which both are numerical strings, two in which one is and the other is not and lastly when both are just mere strings, below is my code:

```
$_POST['category'] = '231';
$_POST['location'] = 'test query';

 if(isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['category'])){


  $categoryQuery = "%{$_POST['category']}%"; 
  $locationQuery = "%{$_POST['location']}%"; 


//case 1
if(is_numeric($categoryQuery) == FALSE && is_numeric($locationQuery) == FALSE){

echo '1-';
}

//case 2
if(is_numeric($categoryQuery) == TRUE && is_numeric($locationQuery) == FALSE){
   echo '2-';
  }

//case 3
 if(is_numeric($categoryQuery) == FALSE && is_numeric($locationQuery) == TRUE){
   echo '3-';
}

//case 4
if(is_numeric($categoryQuery) == TRUE && is_numeric($locationQuery) == TRUE){
 }

 }
```

But no matter the value of the two variables everytime case 1 is executed, anyone know how I can get passed this issue?

I am a full time java/Android developer so my logic might be off

Comment: Your var `$categoryQuery` will never be numeric with the `%` marks surrounding it.  Do your tests first before wrapping them for the query

Comment: well thanks, I have made so much modification to my code that I forgot to remove the %

Comment: add this as an answer I accept it

Comment: Also, if testing for FALSE and/or TRUE, a wiser comparison would perhaps be to use `===` instead of `==`. But yes, as others have pointed out, do the checks before adding the `%%` for the DB-search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code here:

```
$categoryQuery = "%{$_POST['category']}%"; 
$locationQuery = "%{$_POST['location']}%";
```

is causing your test to fail.  You are wrapping your variables with the `%` marks (ostensibly for a SQL query) before testing whether they are numeric.  Wrapped with these marks, your variables will always be evaluated as strings.

Answer (score 0):

what is this?

```
$categoryQuery = "%{$_POST['category']}%";
$locationQuery = "%{$_POST['location']}%";
```

try this

```
$categoryQuery = $_POST['category'];
$locationQuery = $_POST['location'];
```

your checking to see if it's a number but with your first version there it will never be a number